# Error when concatenating generic typescript arrays

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a custom "chunking" function similar to the one provided by lodash but have been running into problems with generics and arrays.

This is the function code:

```
function chunk<T>(arr: T[], chunkSize: number, cache: T[] = []): T[] {
    const tmp = [...arr];
    if (chunkSize <= 0) return cache;
    while (tmp.length) cache.push(tmp.splice(0, chunkSize));
    return cache;
}
```

The compilation error occurs in when trying to push the splice onto the `cache` array:

```
Argument of type 'T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T[]'.ts(2345)
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want your `cache` to be an array of arrays, i.e.

```
function chunk<T>(arr: T[], chunkSize: number, cache: T[][] = []): T[][] {
```

For reference, the type definition of lodash `chunk` function look like this:

```
chunk<T>(
    array: List<T> | null | undefined,
    size?: number
): T[][];
```

See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/array.d.ts

Comment: This worked great, thanks! Great reference to the lodash definitions, I think that's a good place to start next time.

Answer (score 0):

- `tmp.splice(0, chunkSize)` return an array `T[]`
- `cache` is `T[]` so its item is `T`.
- If you use `cache.push(tmp.splice(0, chunkSize))` means you push `T[]` as an item => you got the error.
- If you want to store `tmp.splice(0, chunkSize)` in `cache` you need to update `cache` type and return type. `function chunk<T>(arr: T[], chunkSize: number, cache: T[][] = []): T[][] {...}`
- I create a [Codesandbox to demonstrate it](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wozniak-qg9wn?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Unfortunately this created a flat array, I was looking for an array of arrays. Maybe I should've been more clear in the description.

Comment: I updated my answer and codesandbox based on your requirements.